# BLE send passkey programmatically

Tags: ios, send, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbcentralmanager

When i connect my device to my peripheral, he asks me a passkey (a pop-up is shown on the device). I want to send this passkey programmatically during the connection.

I'm using CBCentralManager but I can't find a way to send it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this.  This is part of the security model.  If your BLE peripheral specifies that encryption is required to access one of its characteristics then pairing is required.  The passkey is collected by iOS, not your application, and your application does not have any access to the passkey or the pairing/bonding process

Comment: Also, even if you had full control of the device (like a BLE dongle for your PC), being able to send the passkey over the air would defeat the hole purpose of having a passkey. If memory serves you'll not be able to send any data packets while the pairing procedure is ongoing.

Comment: It's not a *necessary* part of the security model. PINs could be transmitted by scanning a QR code for example. This is possible on Android. (Of course the real solution is to support OOB pairing, but neither iOS nor Android do.)