# Programmatic Bluetooth PIN on iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, pairing

If I obtain the PIN for a BLE device via some out-of-band means (e.g. QR code), is it possible to programmatically tell iOS the PIN so that it doesn't prompt the user when you connect?

I believe it is possible on Android 4.4+ using [`setPin()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#setPin(byte[])). Is there an equivalent on iOS?

Comment: No,there are no APIs for supplying a PIN.  The user must enter it into the system dialog that is presented.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603083/ble-send-passkey-programmatically/23605848#23605848 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589836/ios-bluetooth-le-unable-to-connect-using-stored-pairing-data